# SQL 2008 Set variable select statement errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Having a problem with variables in a stored procedure.

I keep getting errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_ProjectData, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_ProjectData, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@CurrentVersion".
```

The second variable (@CurrentVersion) is the problem one. I initially created the procedure without that one and it was fine. Now I need to update it but it just will not accept the second variable that I am trying to set its value using a select statement.

I have been round and round using posts on here and all sorts of other sites trying "Set", "Select" playing around with the formatting along the way but have come up with nothing.

This is the complete procedure, any help greatly appreciated as ever.

```
  USE [ic_intranet]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_ProjectData]    Script Date: 07/04/2016 12:29:06 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ProjectData]
        @ProjectRef int,
        @CurrentVersion decimal(4, 2)

        SELECT @CurrentVersion = VersionNumber FROM t_ProjectEquipmentVersions WHERE CurrentVersion = 'true' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef

    AS

    SELECT
    t_Projects.JobNumber,
    t_Projects.JobName,
    t_Projects.ProjectType,
    t_Projects.ProjectStatus,
    t_Projects.JobCode,
    t_Projects.TargetCompleteDate,
    t_Projects.ActualFinishDate,
    t_Projects.LocationCountry,
    t_Projects.LocationTown,
    t_Projects.SoldDate,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPCost) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS TotalValueBuy, 
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPRetail) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS TotalValueSell,
    (SELECT COUNT(Ordered) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '1' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef) GROUP BY Ordered) AS OrderedItems,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPCost) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '1' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS OrderedValueBuy,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPRetail) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '1' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS OrderedValueSell,
    (SELECT COUNT(Ordered) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '0' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef) GROUP BY Ordered) AS NotOrderedItems,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPCost) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '0' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS NotOrderedValueBuy,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPRetail) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '0' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS NotOrderedValueSell,
    t_EmployeeProjectManager.Firstname AS ProjectManagerFirstname, 
    t_EmployeeProjectManager.Surname AS ProjectManagerSurname,
    t_EmployeeLeadEngineer.Firstname AS LeadEngineerFirstname, 
    t_EmployeeLeadEngineer.Surname AS LeadEngineerSurname,
    t_EmployeeSalesRep.Firstname AS SalesRepFirstname, 
    t_EmployeeSalesRep.Surname AS SalesRepSurname,
    t_EmployeeDesigner.Firstname AS DesignerFirstname, 
    t_EmployeeDesigner.Surname AS DesignerSurname
    FROM t_Projects
    LEFT JOIN t_Employee AS t_EmployeeProjectManager ON t_Projects.ProjectManager = t_EmployeeProjectManager.ID
    LEFT JOIN t_Employee AS t_EmployeeLeadEngineer ON t_Projects.LeadEngineer = t_EmployeeLeadEngineer.ID
    LEFT JOIN t_Employee AS t_EmployeeSalesRep ON t_Projects.SalesRep = t_EmployeeSalesRep.ID
    LEFT JOIN t_Employee AS t_EmployeeDesigner ON t_Projects.Designer = t_EmployeeDesigner.ID
    WHERE JobNumber = @ProjectRef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance,

Write the `Select` Statement after the `AS` statement,

```
USE [ic_intranet]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_ProjectData]    Script Date: 07/04/2016 12:29:06 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ProjectData]
        @ProjectRef int,
        @CurrentVersion decimal(4, 2)


    AS


        SELECT @CurrentVersion = VersionNumber FROM t_ProjectEquipmentVersions WHERE CurrentVersion = 'true' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef

    SELECT
    t_Projects.JobNumber,
    t_Projects.JobName,
    t_Projects.ProjectType,
    t_Projects.ProjectStatus,
    t_Projects.JobCode,
    t_Projects.TargetCompleteDate,
    t_Projects.ActualFinishDate,
    t_Projects.LocationCountry,
    t_Projects.LocationTown,
    t_Projects.SoldDate,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPCost) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS TotalValueBuy, 
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPRetail) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS TotalValueSell,
    (SELECT COUNT(Ordered) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '1' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef) GROUP BY Ordered) AS OrderedItems,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPCost) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '1' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS OrderedValueBuy,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPRetail) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '1' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS OrderedValueSell,
    (SELECT COUNT(Ordered) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '0' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef) GROUP BY Ordered) AS NotOrderedItems,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPCost) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '0' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS NotOrderedValueBuy,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectGBPRetail) FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment WHERE (Ordered = '0' and JobNumber = @ProjectRef)) AS NotOrderedValueSell,
    t_EmployeeProjectManager.Firstname AS ProjectManagerFirstname, 
    t_EmployeeProjectManager.Surname AS ProjectManagerSurname,
    t_EmployeeLeadEngineer.Firstname AS LeadEngineerFirstname, 
    t_EmployeeLeadEngineer.Surname AS LeadEngineerSurname,
    t_EmployeeSalesRep.Firstname AS SalesRepFirstname, 
    t_EmployeeSalesRep.Surname AS SalesRepSurname,
    t_EmployeeDesigner.Firstname AS DesignerFirstname, 
    t_EmployeeDesigner.Surname AS DesignerSurname
    FROM t_Projects
    LEFT JOIN t_Employee AS t_EmployeeProjectManager ON t_Projects.ProjectManager = t_EmployeeProjectManager.ID
    LEFT JOIN t_Employee AS t_EmployeeLeadEngineer ON t_Projects.LeadEngineer = t_EmployeeLeadEngineer.ID
    LEFT JOIN t_Employee AS t_EmployeeSalesRep ON t_Projects.SalesRep = t_EmployeeSalesRep.ID
    LEFT JOIN t_Employee AS t_EmployeeDesigner ON t_Projects.Designer = t_EmployeeDesigner.ID
    WHERE JobNumber = @ProjectRef
```

Comment: Thanks Lucky! Thought it would be something really simple!

Comment: @DA082 Glad to help. Don't forget to mark it as ans and given UP vote. So that there won't be multiple answers for this question.